# Update Map Table To Fix Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with duplicate rows that need to be removed. The issue is that both rows may have things in other tables that are relevant. My table `Table1` looks something like this:

```
PK | A | ...
----------------
1  | 1 | ...
2  | 5 | ...
3  | 1 | ...
....
```

So in this case row 1 and row 3 are duplicates. I want to keep the one with the minimum PK. I have another table `Table2` which also has a PK and all rows are mapped to `Table1` by a map table `T1T2Map`. The map table looks like this:

```
PK | T1PK | T2PK
-----------------
1  | 1    | 2
2  | 5    | 6
3  | 3    | 7
....
```

I can get all of the duplicate rows in `Table1` with this query:

```
SELECT PK FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY PK) NO,*
        FROM Table1) AS T1 WHERE NO = 2
```

What I want to do is change all of the `3`s in the `T1PK` column to `1`.

Here is my ugly update statement that updates 0 rows:

```
update T1T2Map
set PK =(SELECT PK FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY PK) NO,*
            FROM Table1) AS T2 WHERE NO = 1 and T2.PrintKey = (SELECT A FROM Table1 WHERE PK = T1T2Map.T1PK))
where T1PK in(SELECT PK
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY PK) NO,*
        FROM Table1) AS T1 WHERE NO = 2)
```

It seems like there should be an easier way to do this, but I am missing it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to use a cte to use the WHERE NO = 2

Answer (score 1):

This is just a start
You need a cte in order to use the NO like a column

```
with cte (PK,A,NO)
as  
(
    SELECT PK, A, 
           minPK = Min(PK) over (PARTITION BY A), 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY PK) NO
      FROM Table1
)
select cte.pk, cte.a, cte.minPK, change.T1PK  
  from cte   
  join T1T2Map as change 
    on change.T1PK = cte.PK 
   and cte.NO > 1
```

I think you want to set change.T1PK = cte.minPK
I think you know how an update works - test with a select

I think this is the update
This updates

```
update T1T2Map 
   set change.T1PK = keep.T1PK
  from cte  
  join T1T2Map as keep 
    on keep.T1PK = cte.PK 
   and cte.NO = 1 
  join T1T2Map as change 
    on change.T1PK = cte.PK 
   and cte.NO > 1
```

Comment: It seems like using a CTE would simplify things greatly. Thanks!

Comment: Your joins don't quite work. You are joining on `NO = 1` and on `NO > 1`, so it returns nothing. Instead I added the `A` column to the map table and then deleted it when I was done. Thanks for all your help though.

Comment: Yes, what I would do is modify the CTE to return the min PK so it was one join